# PyAutoGUI isn't working, always getting attribute error: CGDisplayPixelsWide

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I've been reading through the internet for an answer and I cannot find anything! So I'm hoping you can help me with this problem. Finally, I've successfully installed it, but now I can not run ANY function and it's getting very annoying. I'll do something as simple as:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.onScreen(0, 2)
```

And boom! Error, I try every function on their "Cheat Sheet" and the same error!

```
AttributeError: CGDisplayPixelsWide
```

I've searched through the module, I've searched through the internet, and now I'm going to you! Please help me, I was really excited to use the functions this module offers.

PS - I'm on macOS Sierra